# Как разобрать массив и добавлять элементы оттуда в select/option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я выбираю первый `select` и в зависимости от значения `value` (из первого селекта) у меня строится второй `select`. т.е.
1) я отправляю get-запрос с параметром `code` в контроллер
2) в контроллере на основе параметра `code` строиться массив.
3) я рендерю этот массив в формате `.json`, делаю эндпоинт

Все хорошо, данные из `json` приходят в виде массива

```
["Альметьевск г", "Воронеж г", "Липецк г"]
```

Но подставлять во второй `select` не получается.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#country_id').change(function () {
      var country_id = $(this).val();
      $('#region_id').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');

      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '/delivery.json',
          data: { code: country_id },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result) {
            for (i=0;i<result.lenght;i++) {
              // Как здесь подставлять option в select?
              // result = ["Альметьевск г", "Воронеж г", "Липецк г"]
              $('<option value="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + result[i] + '</option>').appendTo('#region_id');
            };

            $('#region_id').html(options);
            $('#region_id').attr('disabled', false);
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Сама форма такая:

```
<form action="/baskets" data-remote="true">
    <p>Город</p>
    <select name="country_id" id="country_id">
        <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
        <% @city.sort.each do |city| %>
          <option value="<%=city[1]%>"><%= city[0] %> </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>

    <br><br>
    <p>Пункт выдачи:</p>
    <!-- Вот сюда подставляться должно -->
    <select name="region_id" id="region_id" disabled="disabled" data-remote="true">
        <option value="0">- выберите пункт -</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Для начала, у вас нет селектора '.region_id'

Comment: И кроме того надо до цикла прeобразовать `json` в `array`  ՝$.parseJSON(result)՝.

Comment: ) попутал, но не в этом дело. все равно ничего не строиться

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Но в result у меня уже массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 ошибки:

- у вас нет селектора `.region_id`;
- свойства `lenght` не существует, а вот `length` есть;
- у элементов массива нет атрибута `id`. Чтобы узнать индекс элемента для подстановки в `value`, используйте `.indexOf()` или подставляйте туда счетчик.

```js
var result = ["Альметьевск г", "Воронеж г", "Липецк г"];
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  // Как здесь подставлять option в select?
  // result = ["Альметьевск г", "Воронеж г", "Липецк г"]
  $('<option value="' + i + '">' + result[i] + '</option>').appendTo('#region_id');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="region_id" id="region_id" data-remote="true">
  <option value="0">- выберите пункт -</option>
</select>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, невнимательность меня сгубила

Comment: А ещё нельзя вызвать `$(this)` в ajax, так как будет вызываться объект AJAX, а не элемент, в котором он находится